# Modifying existing corporate powerpoint template for use in rmarkdown: Could not find shape for Powerpoint content

Tags: r-markdown, powerpoint

I have an existing corporate powerpoint template that I must use. What must I change in the template so that I can use it in rmarkdown? I'm currently getting "Could not find shape for Powerpoint content".

edit: I get this error when I run

```
pandoc --to pptx --reference-doc breed_wit_met_dianummering.potx --output ScrumIntro.pptx ScrumIntro.md
```

The template I use is at https://company-122895.frontify.com/api/attachment/download/FBcAVUTBYwQUa6UUQtF03Eqt1qDCsN0zgI_LVSjKW85J1PXf4e7m3HRWI-OBE_UYgsjGK2uXc2yLCwDYxzAiMQ, but I already know it doesn't conform to the expectations of pandoc; I'm looking for information on what I should do to create a template that will conform (not necessarily starting with this one, just in general). I'm OK with starting from scratch, but I don't know exactly what must be in place in a template to meet pandoc's expectations.

Comment: You need to give us a lot more detail.  A reproducible example might be hard if the template is unavailable to us, but at the least you need to tell us what you did, and when that message showed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The required structure in the powerpoint template + a script which will report deviations can be found at https://gist.github.com/retorquere/9053b3dee7b2ce62382e005c73592391 . The rules are:

- There must be at least 4 slides in the slide masters, named ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout[1-4].xml
- ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml is a title slide, and must:

  - have a p:ph element with type="ctrTitle"
  - have a p:ph element with type="subTitle"
  - have a p:ph element with type="dt"
- ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml is a title + content slide, and must:

  - have a p:ph element with type="title"
  - have a p:ph element *without* a type attribute
- ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout3.xml is a section header slide, and must:

  - have a p:ph element with either type="title" or type="ctrTitle"
- ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml is a title + two-content slide, and must:

  - have a p:ph element with type="title"
  - have at least two p:ph elements *without* a type attribute

you can upload your template to https://rmarkdown-office-template.herokuapp.com/ and it will test against these rules, and report what is missing in these slides if they don't comply with the rules.

Comment: The gist is not available anymore. However, your explanation of rules are very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @retorquere The template used for Rstudio webinar - https://github.com/sol-eng/powerpoint/blob/master/webinar/webinar-template.pptx - - does not validate... Do you have a template to share that fully validate?

Comment: Their own template currently does not validate against these rules. I'm discussing the issue at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5402

Comment: unfortunately the herokuapp throws an error when I try to open it, is there another way to access it?

Comment: The script at https://gist.github.com/retorquere/9053b3dee7b2ce62382e005c73592391 is still up. Unfortunately I let the heroku app expire when they started charging, and it turns out that heroku app was the only repository I had of it.